# How to retrieve data displayed in current page of MUI Data Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Is there any way to get the data displayed by MUI Data Grid in the current page ?

My case is the following :
I have a Data Grid displaying notifications, and I want to set the unreads one to read when they are displayed.
However, if there is more than one page of unread notifications, I just want to mark as read the one displayed in the current page.

I tried something with updating the parent state from column definition, but a react warning prompt me not to do that : `` Cannot update a component (`Notifications`) while rendering a different component (`Message`) ``

```
           field: "message",
           headerName: "Message",
           flex: 1,
           renderCell: (params) => (
               <Message
                   row={params.row}
                   onSetUnread={(notif) => {
                       if (unread.indexOf(notif) === -1) {
                           setUnread((previous) => [...previous, notif]);
                       }
                   }}
               />
           ),
       },
```

Any help would be appreciated !

**EDIT** :
I still couldn't find any solution, I might start trying something as a custom table that would tell me what data is displayed